# how to echo multidimension array using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, echo

I have the following array, I need to display the names on a form.
How can I do this via `foreach()` loop?

What I am trying is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [to_user_name] => John
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [to_user_name] => Mike
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was treating it like a single array and then i realized it is a multidimensino array and the following worked, i hope this helps someone else too

```
foreach ($messages->getMessage('recipient_names') as $section => $items ){
    foreach ($items as $key => $value){
        echo "$value, ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $myArray as $subArray ) {
    echo $subArray["to_user_name"];
}
```

It's not clear how you want to use those values in your form, but just `echo` the values wherever you'd need them, e.g.,

```
foreach( $myArray as $subArray ) {
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"user_name\" value=\"" . $subArray["to_user_name"] . "\">";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to see the content you can use

```
print_r($your_array);
```

For developing purpose you need to use for/foreach loop

```
foreach($your_array as $array_temp)
{
foreach($array_temp as $item)
{
echo $item;
}
}
```